# Does require()-ing a library in node.js make my code a "derived work" for the purposes of (A)GPL?

Tags: javascript, licensing, node.js

If someone publishes `foo.js` under GPL, and I `require("foo")` in my node.js app, is my code a "derived work" for the purposes of GPL?

Does the situation change (i.e. does it matter) if the library is AGPL, and I'm running this code on a server?

Edit: I'm also not sure if it matters whether it's (A)GPL v2 or v3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Probably.](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#LinkingWithGPL) you'll need a GPL-compatible license, whatever that means.

Thankfully most js libraries are MIT licensed, so we don't have to worry about legalese.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is LGPL, you shouldn't need to license it under LGPL. If it is GPL, then you probably would, unless you use child processes for something like ffmpeg.

AGPL/GPL does not affect if your work is "derived"; GPL requires you to distribute source code if you distribute the binary, AGPL requires you to distribute source code if you use it over a network.